# Reverse a DNA string sequence and find its complementary

Tags: c, dna-sequence

I am having a hard time doing C program for this. I have come up to use strrev function for reversing a string. However, in finding the complementary, it always says COMPARISON BETWEEN POINTER AND INTEGER.

Please correct my if else statement. I badly need it. Thank you.

```c
#include<stdio.h> // define the header file
#include<string.h>
void main() {  // define the main function
    char str[100];
    char comp[100];
    printf("\nHi! \n Please input a string: ");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    printf("Reversed String: %s", strrev(str));
    
    if(str == 'a')
    comp=='t';
    else if(str == 't')
    comp=='a';
    else if(str == 'g')
    comp=='c';
    else if(str == 'c')
    comp=='g';

    printf("\nComplementary: %s",comp);
}
```

Comment: The reason it says 'comparison between pointer and integer' is that in each of the 8 lines, you compare a pointer (`str` or `comp`) with an integer (`'a'`, `'c`', `'g'`, `'t`').  Array names become pointers; you need to index into the array to get at the characters stored in the array.  And you need to do assignments, not comparisons, in the action statements after the `if` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use assignment operator = to assign (not ==, which is for comparison). You need to loop over the elements of the string — for example, `for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)` and refer to the characters using `str[i]` in the body of the loop setting up the complementary string.

You might need to worry about upper-case vs lower-case letters too, I think — I've seen ACGT used more often than acgt for the DNA base molecules.  The code below identifies invalid letters, but continues anyway.

Note that while Microsoft provides the `strrev()` function, it is not standardized either by the C standard or by POSIX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    char comp[100];

    printf("\nHi!\nPlease input a DNA string (lower-case acgt): ");
    scanf("%99s", str);
    printf("Reversed String: %s\n", strrev(str));
    
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == 'a')
            comp[i] = 't';
        else if (str[i] == 't')
            comp[i] = 'a';
        else if (str[i] == 'g')
            comp[i] = 'c';
        else if (str[i] == 'c')
            comp[i] = 'g';
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid DNA character '%c' at position %zu\n", str[i], i);
            comp[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    comp[i] = '\0';  // Make sure the complementary string is null terminated

    printf("\nComplementary: %s\n", comp);
    return 0;
}
```